# How to Add FragmentActivity to FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

**scenario:**
I have the `mainActivity` in which it holds the default `game list fragment` When user clicks an item on the list it should show the `FragmentActivity` that contains a viewpager with two tabs inside the `framelayout` basically replacing the default game `list fragment`.

**question:** how can I add `FragmentActivity` to the `FrameLayout`?

**what I have tried:**

```
//this throws an error because the fragment cannot be casted to `FragmentActivity`
Fragment fragment = (NewsTopicsFragment) ft.findFragmentById(R.id.container);

                    //Fragment mNewsTopicsFragment =(Fragment) new NewsTopicsFragment();
                    //mNewsTopicsFragment.setGame(mGame);

                    getActivity()
                        .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, mNewsTopicsFragment)
                            .commit();
```

Comment: `FragmentActivity` is component which work as a Activity so it's not possible to add `FragmentActivity` to FrameLayout same as we add Fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace this fragmentActivity by a fragment. You can nest fragments so that shouldn't be a big change and then you'll be able to add the fragment to the frameLayout.